# Selecting OU from if statement in function

Tags: powershell, winforms, if-statement, active-directory, ou

I am trying to change the OU path of the new user being made in the function of creating the user. I am running into the issue of the OU path coming back as NULL with this if statement and am unsure why. Any help would be great!

```
$dropdown_FirstOU = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$dropdown_FirstOU.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(55,110)
$dropdown_FirstOU.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,40)
$dropdown_FirstOU.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList
$dropdown_FirstOU.Items.AddRange($Sites)
$Form_SelectOU.Controls.Add($dropdown_FirstOU)

if ($dropdown_FirstOU -eq "Aberdeen") {

    $OU = "OU=Aberdeen,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"

} elseif ($dropdown_FirstOU -eq "Kingpin") {
   
    $OU = "OU=Kingpin,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"

}
```

Comment: `$OU` would be `$null` if `$dropdown_FirstOU` is not Aberdeen or Kingpin. What is the value of `$dropdown_FirstOU` or how is it obtained?

Comment: Can you include a fully [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question please? At the moment it is difficult to diagnose because no one can see where `$dropdown_FirstOU` is being set, but I suspect that the value is empty or not one of the two values it is being tested against.

Comment: $dropdown_FirstOU = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $dropdown_FirstOU.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(55,110)
    $dropdown_FirstOU.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,40)
    $dropdown_FirstOU.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList
    $dropdown_FirstOU.Items.AddRange($Sites)
    $Form_SelectOU.Controls.Add($dropdown_FirstOU)

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue, I wasn't adding the .Text after the dropdown combo box so the script wasn't reading the text in the combo box!

```
    if ($dropdown_FirstOU.Text -eq "Aberdeen") {

        $OU = "OU=Aberdeen,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"

    } elseif ($dropdown_FirstOU.Text -eq "Kingpin") {

        $OU = "OU=Kingpin,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"

    }
```

Comment: Without `if() .. else`:  `$OU = "OU=$($dropdown_FirstOU.Text),OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

**$OU** is null because the value of **$dropdown_FirstOU** is neither **Aberdeen** nor **Kingpin**.

If the **$dropdown_FirstOU** vaule is **Aberdeen**, the **$OU** value will be **OU=Aberdeen,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local**

Similarly for the **Kingpin**.

[image]